# Mongo Query : lot of parameters to search on. not able to figure out

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What i have :

1. list of company names : [bmw, tata, ferrari,...]
2. transmission : Manual or Automatic3.
3. car color :   Red or White etc
4. model year : 2010 to 2014
5. Min Price  & Max Price. --> Price range

**===========================================================================**

What i can do now : if i had only one object (ie. one company in `companies`) then i would do something like :

```
query = {{transmission_type : transmission}, {color : car_color}, {year : model_year}, { $range: [ 0, "$PriceInINR", 25 ] }  }
```

`db.companies.cars.find(query)`

**But**  here first there are a lot of companies, and then each company has list of cars.

**How can i do such a query**.

1. I want a one query which considers the price range.
2. and Another with no price range condition.

*Early thoughts* : I thought that i could do query each company separately as i know company names. so finding the result individually and then push the to an array.

**How should i do this, any other suggestions?**

**Tried this one too, but doesn't seem to work, HELP**

```
db.companies.aggregate([ 

  { $match: { company_name: { $in: ["gmc"] } } },

  { $unwind: "$cars" },

  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$cars" } },

  {

    $match: {

      transmission_type: "Automatic",

      color: "Metallic White",

      year: 2015,

      price: { $gt: 0, $lt: 99999999 }

    }

  }

])
```

**===========================================================================**

psudo structure of `companies` collection

```
Companies {
    bmw: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },car3 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
        ],

    jaguar: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
          ],
    ferrari [
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --} 
        ]   
}
```

**===========================================================================**
Actual structure of `companies` collection in mongo db

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b78cc390cca71aa0e5"),
        "company_location" : "USA",
        "company_name" : "buick",
        "__v" : 0,
        "cars" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de56"),
                        "model" : "ENCLAVE",
                        "year" : 2014,
                        "PriceInINR" : 2537993,
                        "trim" : "Leather FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Silver",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de5d"),
                        "model" : "LaCrosse",
                        "year" : 2011,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4677427,
                        "trim" : "CXL FWD",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Grey",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b7d1a7c2156417de8e"),
                        "model" : "ENCORE",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4808616,
                        "trim" : "Leather FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "1.4L L4 DOHC 16V TURBO",
                        "color" : "Yellow",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b7d1a7c2156417dece"),
                        "model" : "LaCrosse",
                        "year" : 2011,
                        "PriceInINR" : 868875,
                        "trim" : "CXL FWD",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V",
                        "color" : "Grey",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b65a"),
                        "model" : "VERANO",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4380113,
                        "trim" : "Base",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V FFV",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b78cc390cca71aa0e7"),
        "company_location" : "USA",
        "company_name" : "gmc",
        "__v" : 0,
        "cars" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de57"),
                        "model" : "TERRAIN",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3851710,
                        "trim" : "SLE2 FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V FFV",
                        "color" : "Yellow",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de5b"),
                        "model" : "YUKON",
                        "year" : 2015,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3129397,
                        "trim" : "SLE 2WD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "5.3L V8 OHV 16V",
                        "color" : "Silver",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },            
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b659"),
                        "model" : "SIERRA 1500",
                        "year" : 2014,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3649025,
                        "trim" : "SLE Crew Cab 2WD",
                        "engine" : "CREW CAB PICKUP 4-DR",
                        "body" : "5.3L V8 OHV 16V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b666"),
                        "model" : "TERRAIN",
                        "year" : 2012,
                        "PriceInINR" : 1896832,
                        "trim" : "SLT1 FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.0L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b650"),
                        "model" : "ACADIA",
                        "year" : 2012,
                        "PriceInINR" : 2541355,
                        "trim" : "Denali AWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Curious dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243910/mongodb-find-query-in-a-collection?

Comment: Man i really need help, i have not worked with mongo, this is my first time, i was able to do basic stuff but i am not able to figure this out. i am in a competetion, and none of my team mate know how to do it.

Comment: Your "Tried this one too" query looks like it should work. What's not working about it?

Comment: @JohnnyHK 
it  neither freezes, nor my db crashes --> just there is no output but the command does get executed. as the pointer comes onto new line.

Comment: The way you debug an aggregate pipeline is to comment out all but the first stage, make sure that its output is what your expecting, then uncomment the second stage, etc.

Comment: @JohnnyHK that is a really good advice, thanks. let me try that and ill get back to you

Comment: @JohnnyHK Man, your adivice changed my life, at least for today :) it worked, i was the one who was doing it wrong. a very very silly mistake.   Some time advices like this can have so much effect. **thanks man**